# In IE with compatibility mode JQuery .val() not working

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have been tasked with fixing a "but" on a web app. The issue is that I have found that when I call .val() in jQuery on a text field that is set as a type search, it returns nothing.

The code is

```
$('input[type=search],select').each(function(){
    console.log("looking at " + $(this).val() + ":"+defaultValue+ ":"+areDatesValid+":"$(this)); 
    //Will only enable Search Button atleast one field has data and the datefields are of correct format or empty
    if ( $(this).val() !="" && $(this).val() !=defaultValue && areDatesValid == true)
    {
        divClassWithInputVal = $(this).attr("class");   
        $("input[id=enabledSection]").val(divClassWithInputVal);
        $('#searchButton').removeAttr("disabled");  
    }
});
```

It is working properly in Web Kit (Chrome, Edge) and in IE11, but it does not work in IE7 (and to those that say why fix it in IE7, I would love to ignore that as IE7 is so old and should be put out to pasture, but since customers are complaining that it does not work for them, I am stuck with fixing it)

`console.log` was added to figure out what was going on, and in IE7 mode the $(this).val() always returns nothing. jQuery version is 1.6.1

I am unable to find any information, most of my searches returns results from 9+ years ago (not surprised there)

Comment: Start by attempting to get the value *without* jquery. That means, `this.value`. If the result is the same, next step would be to ensure `this` is what you think it is in that scenario.

Comment: You really still need to support IE7 and jQuery 1.6.1? My sympathies.

Comment: @kevin b Well the this.value keeps returning empty.  I know that this should be correct as in chrome, IE11 and edge it has the right value.

Comment: that's a decent start. i wouldn't be so quick to assume jquery is performing the same in IE7 vs 11, check a separate property that would be unique to the input, like its name.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if [type=search] wasn't returning the inputs at all. In newer versions of jQuery i would expect that result, but 1.6 might still have the IE7 support.

Comment: @Kevin B I think you are right, I just inspected the DOM, the type is not search it is text in IE7.  So I need to figure out if it IE7 or other and pick the right type (search or text)  Thanks.

Comment: yeah... now that I think about it I don't think any version of jquery would be able to correct for that. Use a classname instead for your selection rather than needing an if/else

Comment: @Kevin B thanks that was a good idea with the class idea, if you could type all this up as an answer I will accept it, still testing, test IE7, and IE11, jsut need to test edge and chrome now.  But I am sure it will work, as I just added a ,.classname to the selector